# Setting the value of a label in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have following label in my web application

```
<h:outputLabel id="yearLabel" value="?" style="font-weight:bold"/>
```

In the controller of that page I want to set the text of this label to some value (in Java).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind it to a bean property the usual way.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    private String label;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        label = "Year"; 
    }

    // ...
}
```

with

```
<h:outputLabel ... value="#{bean.label}" />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, I'm not sure what the functional requirement for this all is, so I can't tell if you're going in the right direction or not as to solving the requirement, but have you considered using resource bundles?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The web application is a simulation. The label indicates the current year. The user presses a button, simulation for a year is performed and then the label is set to the next year. I. e. at the beginning, the label shows `2012`, after pressing the button  - `2013`, after next pressing - `2014` etc.

Comment: I modified the code as you told, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I suppose that I need to notify the "view layer" that the value of the property has changed and the label needs to be redrawn. Is it possible?

Comment: Ah OK. Well, as you noticed, it's not different from displaying bean properties in other JSF components like `h:outputText`, `h:inputText`, etc. I only wonder if it is really a valid usage for a `<label>`. I don't see anywhere a `for` attribute. Edit: As to the problem that it doesn't work, maybe you fired an ajax request and forgot to re-render the component? You have got to be more specific in "doesn't work". Elaborate the problem in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective.

Comment: In that case you need to give your label an `id`. After executing some action (triggered by a (command)button) you need to do an update on that `id` of the outputLabel in order to re-fetch the new year from the bean.

Comment: @BalusC How can I re-render a component with a known `id`?

Comment: Just specify it in `<f:ajax render>` as shown in the average sane JSF tutorial. Press `Ask Question` if you stucks somwhow. This goes offtopic.

Comment: @BalusC Question about `<f:ajax render>` can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996108/update-a-label-in-jsf-primefaces